# Haskell map function with where statement in F#

Tags: haskell, f#

I am trying to port this haskell function to F#

```
subs        ::  [a] -> [[a]]
subs []     =   [[]]
subs (x:xs) =   ys ++ map (x:) ys
                where 
                   ys = subs xs
```

example

subs [1,2,3]

returns:

[[],[3],[2],[2,3],[1],[1,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]]

returns all sub sequences of a list, which are given by all possible combination of excluding or including each element

....

I am having issues with the 'where' statement, which recursively generates the other list 'ys'.

I am also not sure I port the predicate '(x:)' correctly to '(fun i -> i)'.

This is as much of the F# statement I can figure out.

```
let rec subs list =
    match list with
        | [] -> [[]]
        | x::xs -> List.map (fun i -> i) xs
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just a side note, this is the powerset of a set.

Comment: Also, note that in Haskell, this can be written simply as `import Control.Monad; subs = filterM $ const [False, True]`

Comment: `(x:)` is not a predicate, it is a "section" expression (basically a partial application of the `:` operator), which is equivalent to `(\ys -> x:ys)` or, in F#, `(fun ys -> x :: ys)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the F#:

```
let rec subs list =    
    match list with        
    | [] -> [[]]        
    | x::xs -> 
        let ys = subs xs
        ys @ List.map (fun t -> x::t) ys

printfn "%A" (subs [1;2;3])
```

A Haskell `where` is pretty much just like a `let` moved to the bottom.

In F#, `@` is the list concatenation operator, and `::` is cons.

There are no operator sections in F#, so I use a lambda (`fun`).

Comment: I knew you'd get in before me...one of these days you'll be in a meeting or something and I'll beat you to the punch! =) Great answer as always.

Comment: I got lucky; some intranet IT update is about to force me to reboot right now :)

Answer (score 5):

Let's get it to look more like F#. :)

```
let rec subs = function
| [] -> [[]]
| x::xs -> [ for ys in subs xs do
                yield! [ys;x::ys] ]
```